# MySql Query to Avoiding Negative Balance

Tags: mysql, subquery

Is that possible to avoid negative balance using MySql query?
I have the following MySql table:

```
trx_no  trx_date    Opening debit   credit 
1       2019-10-01  200     0       100    
2       2019-10-02  200     0       100     
3       2019-10-03  200     100     0       
4       2019-10-03  200     400     0      
5       2019-10-03  200     0       200      
6       2019-10-04  200     0       100      
7       2019-10-05  200     0       400
```

with this query:

```
SELECT
    trx_no,
    trx_date,
    Opening,
    debit,
    credit,
    Opening + (SELECT SUM(t2.credit - t2.debit)
               FROM MyTable t2
               WHERE t2.trx_no <= t1.trx_no) AS balance
FROM MyTable t1
ORDER BY
    trx_no;
```

I got:

```
trx_no  trx_date    Opening debit   credit   balance
1       2019-10-01  200     0       100      300
2       2019-10-02  200     0       100      400
3       2019-10-03  200     100     0        300
4       2019-10-03  200     400     0       -100
5       2019-10-03  200     0       200      100
6       2019-10-04  200     0       100      200
7       2019-10-05  200     0       400      600
```

You can see that  there is a negative balance (-100) on 2019-10-03. 
Is that possible to make a mysql query to avoid negative balance by **allowing credit calculation first** **if there are debit and credit on the same date**? so the result will become:

```
trx_no  trx_date    Opening debit   credit   balance
    1   2019-10-01  200     0       100      300
    2   2019-10-02  200     0       100      400
    5   2019-10-03  200     0       200      600
    3   2019-10-03  200     100     0        500
    4   2019-10-03  200     400     0        100
    6   2019-10-04  200     0       100      200
    7   2019-10-05  200     0       400      600
```

[**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xkiBp2a7JzW8Qehn7De7ZZ/1)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are intending to achieve. Could you perhaps elaborate using a single transaction number?

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: Hi, I don't want to see negative balance for the reporting. The achievement, if there are debit and credit transactions within the same date then credit transaction should be calculated first

Comment: Hi @forpas, I am using MySql server 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition:

```
WHERE t2.trx_no <= t1.trx_no
```

does not work in your case.
You need the rows ordered by `trx_date`, then by credits first and then debits and finally by `trx_no`.
This code will use a combined column (with concatenation) of these 3 conditions:

```
SELECT
    t1.trx_no,
    t1.trx_date,
    t1.Opening,
    t1.debit,
    t1.credit,
    t1.Opening + (
      SELECT SUM(t2.credit - t2.debit)
      FROM MyTable t2 
      WHERE 
        concat(t2.trx_date, t2.debit > t2.credit, lpad(t2.trx_no, 10, '0')) <=
        concat(t1.trx_date, t1.debit > t1.credit, lpad(t1.trx_no, 10, '0'))
    ) AS balance
FROM MyTable t1
ORDER BY concat(t1.trx_date, t1.debit > t1.credit, lpad(t1.trx_no, 10, '0'))
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nw16n5Ls1AUFb9cAz5Y1wF/3).
Results:

```
| trx_no | trx_date   | Opening | debit | credit | balance |
| ------ | ---------- | ------- | ----- | ------ | ------- |
| 1      | 2019-10-01 | 200     | 0     | 100    | 300     |
| 2      | 2019-10-02 | 200     | 0     | 100    | 400     |
| 5      | 2019-10-03 | 200     | 0     | 200    | 600     |
| 3      | 2019-10-03 | 200     | 100   | 0      | 500     |
| 4      | 2019-10-03 | 200     | 400   | 0      | 100     |
| 6      | 2019-10-04 | 200     | 0     | 100    | 200     |
| 7      | 2019-10-05 | 200     | 0     | 400    | 600     |
```

Comment: One more question, is that possible to make credit  transaction only calculating first if the balance is negative?  So if the balance not negative the sort is as is (no need credit first)

Comment: For this to happen the SUM should be calculated twice for each row. Once to check if it is negative and if it is then reorder. I don't think that this is possible without very complex subqueries in case statements.

Comment: Hi @forpas, could you please help me to make it?

Comment: This is a new requirement that does not belong to this question. Post a new question with new sample data that will demonstrate how you want the output in each case and explain why.

Comment: Here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454140/mysql-query-for-running-balance-correction