# MySql Query for Running Balance Correction

Tags: mysql, subquery

Please someone help me to make a MySql query for running balance correction.

Actually We have very much dirty data that came from other application. Sometimes we got negative balance for normal running balance calculation.

From [the question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451767/mysql-query-to-avoiding-negative-balance) I got an answer but I want  **credit transaction only calculating first if the normal balance calculation is negative so if the balance does not negative then the order of debit and credit within the same date should not change**

Here is the table example:

```
trx_no  trx_date    Opening debit   credit 
1       2019-10-01  200     0       100    
2       2019-10-02  200     0       100     
3       2019-10-03  200     100     0       
4       2019-10-03  200     400     0      
5       2019-10-03  200     0       200      
6       2019-10-04  200     0       100      
7       2019-10-05  200     100     0 
8       2019-10-05  200     0       400
```

For normal balance calculation we got negative balance:

```
trx_no  trx_date    Opening debit   credit   balance
    1   2019-10-01  200     0       100      300
    2   2019-10-02  200     0       100      400
    3   2019-10-03  200     100     0        300
    4   2019-10-03  200     400     0        -100  <- negative balance
    5   2019-10-03  200     0       200      100
    6   2019-10-04  200     0       100      200
    7   2019-10-05  200     100     0        100
    8   2019-10-05  200     0       400      500
```

Here is the query I got from @forpas (many thanks) :

```
SELECT
    t1.trx_no,
    t1.trx_date,
    t1.Opening,
    t1.debit,
    t1.credit,
    t1.Opening + (
      SELECT SUM(t2.credit - t2.debit)
      FROM MyTable t2 
      WHERE 
        concat(t2.trx_date, t2.debit > t2.credit, lpad(t2.trx_no, 10, '0')) <=
        concat(t1.trx_date, t1.debit > t1.credit, lpad(t1.trx_no, 10, '0'))
    ) AS balance
FROM MyTable t1
ORDER BY concat(t1.trx_date, t1.debit > t1.credit, lpad(t1.trx_no, 10, '0'))
```

Below is the result for above query, no negative balance but trx_no 8 ordered before trx_no 7:

```
trx_no  trx_date    Opening debit   credit   balance
    1   2019-10-01  200     0       100      300
    2   2019-10-02  200     0       100      400
    5   2019-10-03  200     0       200      600
    3   2019-10-03  200     100     0        500
    4   2019-10-03  200     400     0        100
    6   2019-10-04  200     0       100      200
    8   2019-10-05  200     0       400      600
    7   2019-10-05  200     100     0        500
```

The result what we need is below. Credit transaction only calculating first if the balance is negative. So if the balance not negative the order should not changed:

```
trx_no  trx_date    Opening debit   credit   balance
    1   2019-10-01  200     0       100      300
    2   2019-10-02  200     0       100      400
    5   2019-10-03  200     0       200      600
    3   2019-10-03  200     100     0        500
    4   2019-10-03  200     400     0        100
    6   2019-10-04  200     0       100      200
    7   2019-10-05  200     100     0        100
    8   2019-10-05  200     0       400      500
```

Here is the **[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4PXd7QkZcHgV5sjBWUVTKE/1)**

Comment: What's the point - reordering is not going to guarantee that you don't get a negative balance , and reordering would not give a true representation of what happened on the account (which I presume is txn_no based). Don't you have a current balance you can check against to stop this happening in the first place?

Comment: Hi.. This data came from other application and from other company. The data owner guarantee that the TOTAL balance will not going negative. We only need the correct report and no need database correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done using set based code since you need read ahead and read back. Something procedural could work. Using a cursor and a temporary table I can pretty much accomplish that (you need to add stuff to ensure that cumulative balance does not go negative). From what you say the first transaction can never take the balance negative but I would check for that. Note well the takes from the credit pool may come from a later date than the debit the take is compensating for - since the balance can never go negative then that should not be a problem (sic).
And of course I would not expect the performance to be great.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
create table t
(trx_no int, trx_date date,    Opening int,debit int,  credit int);
insert into t values
(1    ,   '2019-10-01' , 200  ,   0     ,  100),    
(2    ,   '2019-10-02' , 200  ,   0     ,  100),    
(3    ,   '2019-10-03' , 200  ,   100   ,  0  ),     
(4    ,   '2019-10-03' , 200  ,   400   ,  0  ),    
(5    ,   '2019-10-03' , 200  ,   0     ,  200),      
(6    ,   '2019-10-04' , 200  ,   0     ,  100),      
(7    ,   '2019-10-05' , 200  ,   100   ,  0  ),
(8    ,   '2019-10-05' , 200  ,   0     ,  400);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stmT;
create table stmt
(trx_no int, trx_date date,    Opening int,debit int,  credit int, cumbal int);




drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
create procedure p()
begin

 declare v_trx_no int;
 declare v_dt date;
 declare v_debit int;
 declare v_credit int;

 declare h_trx_no int;
 declare h_dt date;
 declare h_credit int;

 declare opbal int;
 declare rbal  int;
 declare done int default 0;
 declare cur cursor for select trx_no,trx_date,debit,credit from t order by trx_date,trx_no;
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

 select opening into opbal from t order by trx_no limit 1;
 set rbal = opbal;
 drop table if exists creditpool;
 create temporary table if not exists creditpool as select trx_no,trx_date,credit,0 as used from t where  credit > 0; 
 #select * from creditpool;
    open cur;
    cursorloop:loop
        fetch cur into v_trx_no,v_dt,v_debit,v_credit;
         if done = true then  
        leave cursorloop;
         end if;  
         if v_credit > 0 and exists (select 1 from creditpool where trx_no = v_trx_no and used = 0) then 
             if v_credit > 0 then
                 insert into stmt values (v_trx_no,v_dt,opbal,v_debit,v_credit, rbal + v_credit);
                 set rbal = rbal + v_credit;
                 update creditpool set used = 1 where trx_no = v_trx_no; 
            end if;
         end if;
         if v_debit > 0 and v_debit <= rbal then
             insert into stmt values (v_trx_no,v_dt,opbal,v_debit,v_credit, rbal - v_debit);
             set rbal = rbal - v_debit;
         elseif v_debit > 0 and v_debit > rbal then
             poolloop: loop
                        select trx_no,trx_date,credit
                            into h_trx_no,h_dt,h_credit
                            from creditpool
                            where used = 0 
                            order by trx_date,trx_no limit 1;
                        insert into stmt values (h_trx_no,h_dt,opbal,0,h_credit, rbal + h_credit);
                        set rbal = rbal + h_credit;
                        update creditpool set used = 1 where trx_no = h_trx_no; 

                        if v_debit <= rbal then
                            insert into stmt values (v_trx_no,v_dt,opbal,v_debit,v_credit, rbal - v_debit);
                            set rbal = rbal - v_debit;
                            leave poolloop;
                        end if;
             end loop poolloop;           
         end if;
    end loop cursorloop;
    close cur;
end $$
delimiter ;
truncate stmt;
call p();
select * from stmt;

+--------+------------+---------+-------+--------+--------+
| trx_no | trx_date   | Opening | debit | credit | cumbal |
+--------+------------+---------+-------+--------+--------+
|      1 | 2019-10-01 |     200 |     0 |    100 |    300 |
|      2 | 2019-10-02 |     200 |     0 |    100 |    400 |
|      3 | 2019-10-03 |     200 |   100 |      0 |    300 |
|      5 | 2019-10-03 |     200 |     0 |    200 |    500 |
|      4 | 2019-10-03 |     200 |   400 |      0 |    100 |
|      6 | 2019-10-04 |     200 |     0 |    100 |    200 |
|      7 | 2019-10-05 |     200 |   100 |      0 |    100 |
|      8 | 2019-10-05 |     200 |     0 |    400 |    500 |
+--------+------------+---------+-------+--------+--------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note the outcome is slightly different to your desired result because a take only occurs when required.

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon, thanks very much for your answer. Your code almost working. Please check the demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jobib9vpyfMLTMxWKaJYsV/3  . On the demo I put additional data. You can see that trx_no 11 has trx_date 2019-10-03 the position (sort) should be within the same date not at the end. By the with my real data right now your code is working well. I am not sure if next time I got my real data has the same case with the dummy data..

Comment: Hmm. I'll get back to you tomorrow

Comment: Amended to include trx_date in cursor select and creditpool select.

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon. Yes! Its working perfect right now. Thanks very much!

Comment: Not sure about that, in hindsight I would add an auto_increment field to stmt